# Mysql Query Optimization for search engine

Tags: mysql, sql

This query takes a lot of time. I used full text mysql

```
SELECT id FROM `Notes` WHERE MATCH(note) AGAINST('lorem' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,1405468
```

How can I reduce the execution time to just 2 or 3 seconds?

I  have put dummy data for testing.

Comment: Not 1 or 2 seconds?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: yes you right want to reduce the time as much as possible

Comment: You already have a FULLTEXT index on the relevant column, so I can't see that there's much scope for improvement

Comment: if i put the order result will be same

Comment: what do you suggest ?